# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^c \sqrt{ \frac{1}{x} \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)} dx$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals

I have been trying to evaluate or at least get a tight upper bound on the definite integral

$$ \int_{0}^c \sqrt{\frac{1}{x} \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)} dx$$

for some $c>1$. The integral converges but the standard estimate $\log(1+\frac{1}{x}) \leq \frac{1}{x}$ would not work, as  $\int_{0}^c \frac{dx}{x} $ diverges. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A first step: As $x\to 0$, you have $\log(1+1/x)\sim \log(1/x) = - \log x$. So approaching to zero, your integrand behaves like $\sqrt{-\log(x) / x}$.

Comment: @DominikS This works only in the interval $(0,1]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*
$$I(c)=\int_0^c \sqrt{\frac{1}{x} \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)} dx\overset {x=\frac1t}{=}\int_{1/c}^\infty t^{-3/2}\sqrt{\ln(1+t)}\,dt$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}\ln t\,\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+t)}{ t}}\bigg|_{1/c}^\infty-\int_{1/c}^\infty\ln t\left(\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+t)}{ t}}\right)^{'}dt$$
$$=\ln c\sqrt{c\ln\big(1+\frac1c\big)}-\int_0^\infty\ln t\left(\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}}\right)^{'}dt+\int_0^{1/c}\ln t\left(\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+t)}{ t}}\right)^{'}dt$$
The second integral converges; I'm not sure that the closed form exists.

Numerically
$$-\int_0^\infty\ln t\left(\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+t)}{ t}}\right)^{'}dt=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln t}{\sqrt{t\ln(1+t)}}\left(\frac{\ln(1+t)}t-\frac1{1+t}\right)dt=2.6256...$$
The third integral can be evaluated via the decomposition of the integrand $(\frac1c<1)$:
$$\int_0^{1/c}\ln t\left(\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}}\right)^{'}dt=-\frac14\int_0^{1/c}\frac{\ln t}{\sqrt{1-\frac t2+\frac{t^2}3+...}}\left(1-\frac {4t}3+...\right)dt$$
$$=\frac{\ln c+1}{4c}-\frac{13}{192}\frac{2\ln c+1}{c^2}+O\Big(\frac{\ln c}{c^3}\Big)$$
Finally,
$$I(c)=\ln c\sqrt{c\ln\Big(1+\frac1c\Big)}+2.6256...+\frac{\ln c+1}{4c}-\frac{13}{192}\frac{2\ln c+1}{c^2}+O\Big(\frac{\ln c}{c^3}\Big)$$

---

Numeric check:

$\,c=4\quad I(4)=4.07058...\,;\quad\text{approximation}=4.06850...$

$\,c=10\quad I(10)=4.95253...\,;\quad\text{approximation}=4.95231...$

Comment: You will have to add some term to make your approximation an upper bound.

Comment: @Kamal Saleh Yes, this is one of the options. Another option is to remove the last (negative) term $\sim 1/c^2$ :)

Answer (score 2):

We could split the integral as follows: $$\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac1x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}dx+\int_1^c\sqrt{\frac1x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}dx=I+\int_1^c\sqrt{\frac1x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}dx$$ And the integrand in the RHS could be bounded by $\frac1x$ and so a strict bound is $$I(c)\le I(1)+\log c$$Which holds only when $c\ge1$, as needed. Finding an expression for $I(1)$ would be interesting...

Edit: This approximation is no where near as good as @Svyatoslav’s estimate. At $c=4$, the upper bound gives $4.214$ and at $c=10$ the upper bound gives $5.13$. However it is great for such few terms.

Edit 2: The upper bound becomes a better approximation for $f(c)$ as $c\rightarrow1$.